# xmodmap setting reverted once every few minute for usb keyboard

Tags: usb, keyboard, xorg, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I have an xmodmap setting that convert CapsLock to control on my laptop, when I am using a usb keyboard, the CapsLock key changes back to its default meaning every once in a few minutes so I need to reissue the xmodmap command. Does anyone know the reason?
I am using debian jessie.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I use "setxkbmap -option caps:ctrl_modifier" (plus some other options) and had similar problem (that is at least year ago). From my notes issue was that XKB options got reset after keyboard was re-attached (e.g., on wakeup from suspend). Solution was to specify these options in server config (in my case /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf, Section "InputClass" / Option "XkbOptions" ...). I don't remember searching / finding any relevant bug I can link though.

Comment: The file doesn't exist on my system. Thank you all the same.